# Vue.js - Using external scripts instead of imported scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js, razor, vuejs2

I am trying to mitigate the Vue scripts that are imported and import them in the CSHTML page instead.

Imagine, I have this in a Vue page:

```
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
```

I want to import the script to be in the head of the CSHTML like this:

```
<script src="URL/vue-chartjs">
```

Is there any way of doing this?

I tried to keep it as simple as possible for you guys to understand because there isn't there much to it, it is just this, I want to load the scripts in the HTML page and not in the Vue page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (if not all) Vue packages provide a [browser version](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#browser) in their *Getting Started* section.

Importing the script in your browser will create a constant in `global` scope (a.k.a. `window` object) that you can use instead of `import`.
In the case of `vue-chartjs`, the global constant is named `VueChartJs`.

Instead of `import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'` you can use `VueChartJs.Line` directly. Following the provided documentation, I created the following example:

```js
Vue.component('bar-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Bar,
  props: {
    chartdata: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    chartData: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    chartOptions: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#app > div { height: 100vh }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <bar-chart :chartdata="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so based on the comment of Tao, I adapted my code and came up with a solution that worked for me!

So I used `VueChartJs.Line` directly and then used the scripts in the Cshtml page.
(I didn't used the Chart in the example, I had my own Chart, I just changed a line of code to use it directly).

I have 2 warnings to give you guys.

Make sure that the scripts that you put load first than the generated webpack bundle(or your bundle), otherwise it will give you an error that you have Vue.js or Charts.Js missing(or any other library that you are using)

Then, be careful about the version of the scripts that you use, they need to be the same as the version of the Vue charts that you are using. I was getting an error where my chart lines would disappear, they would load then disappear right immediately.
I figured that it was the version of the scripts that were loaded were different of my Vue Charts in the `Package.json`.

Thanks for the help Tao and I hope that this thread helps someone that is in the same situation that I was!